# Absolute Risk more than 100%

Tags: biostatistics, relative-risk, absolute-risk

Is it possible for the absolute risk to be more than 100%?

I read the definition of absolute risk is the number of events (good or bad) in treated or control groups, divided by the number of people in that group.

So if one of the individuals in the group has numerous adverse events, couldn't this make the absolute risk more than 100%?

Answer (score 0):

The absolute risk is the probability of an event happening to a person. It can never be more than 100%.

However, if an event can only happen once to a person then the absolute risk is the expected number of events that will happen to a person. If an event can happen more than once, then the risk is no longer the expected number of events.

If the risk is 100%, that implies it WILL happen (to each person). If it happens to me 10 times, and it happens to 9 people zero times, you can't say that it happened to everyone.